# Introduction to the boundary element method, with convergence analysis

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I've looked through several textbooks on the BEM, but while they show how to set up the boundary integral formulation and how to discretize it, none give any indication of what the convergence properties are. I'm particularly interested in the Neumann BEM for elliptic problems, and the conditions under which the solution and its normal derivative converge at the boundary under refinement.

Comment: I would ask on https://mathoverflow.net/ instead